# Button does not work while visit another pagination page or being search (ajax, Laravel)

Tags: javascript, laravel, bootstrap-4

After being searched in the index page, the  button action does not work.
While visiting second page the action button does not work.

**Here is my index page**

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-active-primary btn-sm"
    data-kt-menu-trigger="click" data-kt-menu-placement="bottom-end">   
  {{actions}}

  <span class="svg-icon svg-icon-5 m-0">
     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" </svg>
  </span>
</a>

<div class="menu menu-sub menu-sub-dropdown menu-column menu-rounded 
    menu-gray-600 menu-state-bg-light-primary fw-bold fs-7 w-125px py-4"
    data-kt-menu="true">
<div class="menu-item px-3">
    <a href="{{ route('index.show', $index->id) }}" class="menu-link 
 px-3"> 
       {{View Details}}
    </a>
</div>
```

**Here is the Route**

```
Route::prefix('example')->name('examples.')->group(function () {
        Route::get('', [ExampleController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
    });
```

**Here is the script**

````
  $(document).on("click", "#pagination a, #search_btn, #reset_btn", function() {
    if(this.id == 'reset_btn'){
        $("#searchform").reset();
    }
  $.ajax({
    url: this.dataset.url,
    type: 'get',
    data:  $("#searchform").serialize(),
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
      success: function(data) {
        $("#pagination_data").html(data); 
      },
      failure: function (response) {
          alert(response.responseText);
      },
      error: function (response) {
          alert(response.responseText);
      }        
    });
  }) 
});```
````

Answer (score 4):

Simply solve the bug by inserting the code below into the button function script.

`KTMenu.createInstances();`

Answer (score 0):

```
KTMenu.createInstances();
```

It works, but it is better if you use

```
KTComponents.init();
```

All other components, like Select2, PageLoading, Menu, Scroll etc are initilized with this one call.